# Swap image rollover center of site

Tags: jquery, css, image, center, rollover

For some reason I can't get something to work. All I want to do is to have an image in the center of a page (it's the only thing on the page) and when I rollover it it changes to a different image.

I am able to make the rollover effect with jquery and I am able to center a image on a page. But I can't combine them..Because the rollover effect with jquery is using an absolute position.

Please any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post your code or better provide a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to wrap your image in a div and center that on the page with a position relative so your image would relate to that div instead of the document body.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish both actions with such javascript

```js
$(".container img").hover(function() {  
  $(".container img").toggle();
});
```

and in your HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/140x140&text=Image%201" />
  <img style="display:none;" src="http://www.placehold.it/140x140&text=Image%202" />
</div>
```

a simple **live example**: http://jsbin.com/agirul/1/edit